# Unity MobAd Rewarded Video is not functioning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ads

i have got a strange issue. I've implemented an ad code to the my game and when my player dies, im asking that the player would watch the ad and reborn. When i build and install the apk to my phone, in first play everything works very well. After second attemp, my rewarderAdd.OnAdRewarded function is not working at all. Im controlling the ad state in the game and in second play, i can see that the reward system is not functionning. here is my code

```
  void Start()
    {
        adState = 0;
        gameOverScript = GameObject.Find("GameOver").GetComponent<GameOverCode>();
        kingSCript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<RedKing>();
        isCompleted = false;
        RequestRewardedVideo();
        this.rewardedAd.OnAdRewarded += RewardPlayer;
       // this.rewardedAd.OnAdClosed += PlayerClosed;


    }

    public void RequestRewardedVideo()
    {
        rewardedAd = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;
        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        // Load the rewarded ad with the request.
        this.rewardedAd.LoadAd(request,rewarderID);
        if(rewardedAd.IsLoaded() == true)
        {
            adState = 5;
        }


    }
    private void RewardPlayer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isCompleted = true;
        adState = 1;
        Reward();
    }

    private void PlayerClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(adState != 1)
        {
            adState = -1;
        }
    }


    public void Reward()
    {
        adState = 1;
        kingSCript.Reborn();
    }
    public void ShowVideoRewardAd()
    {
        if (this.rewardedAd.IsLoaded())
        {
            adState = 2;
            isLoaded = true;
            this.rewardedAd.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            isLoaded = false;
        }
    }
```

Why the ad state is not working in second attemp? Every time i re-upload the scene so every code should work as like as the first time but its not working at all!

Comment: For explain the problem, in first attemp my adState change to 1 after watching the ad, but in second attemp its not changing. its stuck on 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is use -= functions for all of the methods. check this script out

```
    void Start()
{

    gameOverScript = GameObject.Find("GameOver").GetComponent<GameOverCode>();
    kingScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<RedKing>();
    adState = 0;
    rewardedID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
    rewardedAd = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;
    isAdLoaded = false;
    RequestRewardedAd();
}


void Update()
{
    Debug.Log(adState);
    if (rewardedAd.IsLoaded())
    {
        isAdLoaded = true;
        Debug.Log("burda");
    }
    if(adState == 1)
    {
        kingScript.Reborn();
    }

    if(adState == -1)
    {
        gameOverScript.FinishTheGame();
    }
    
}



public void RequestRewardedAd()
{
    AdRequest request = AdRequestBuild();
    rewardedAd.LoadAd(request, rewardedID);

    rewardedAd.OnAdLoaded += this.HandleOnRewardedAdLoaded;
    rewardedAd.OnAdRewarded += this.HandleOnAdRewarded;
    rewardedAd.OnAdClosed += this.HandleOnRewardedAdClosed;
}

public void HandleOnRewardedAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Debug.Log("loaded");
    adState = 3;
}
public void HandleOnAdRewarded(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    adState = 1;
    
}
public void HandleOnRewardedAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    rewardedAd.OnAdLoaded -= this.HandleOnRewardedAdLoaded;
    rewardedAd.OnAdRewarded -= this.HandleOnAdRewarded;
    rewardedAd.OnAdClosed -= this.HandleOnRewardedAdClosed;
    if(adState != 1)
    {
        playerAdCount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PlayerDontWatchTheAds");
        playerAdCount++;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlayerDontWatchTheAds", playerAdCount);
        adState = -1;
    }
}
public void ShowRewardAd()
{

    if (rewardedAd.IsLoaded())
    {
        rewardedAd.Show();
    }
}

AdRequest AdRequestBuild()
{
    return new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
}
```